# Copy properties of one object to another object with same base

Tags: c#, inheritance, dataset

The situation...

I am creating a shopping cart for a asp.net site. I have a Cart object which will contain a list of CartItem objects. Rather than create the necessary properties for the CartItem object such as ID, ProductName, Description, Price... I thought it would be clever to simply inherit the datarow from the dataset table like this...

```
public class CartItem : DanubeDataSet.ProductsRow
{
public int Quantity { get; set; }

public CartItem(System.Data.DataRowBuilder rb) : base(rb)
{
    Quantity = 1;
}

public decimal TotalCost
{
    get
    {
        return Quantity * Price;
    }
}
}
```

Now if I acquire DanubeDataSet.ProductsTable object containing a row that I want, how do I set all the properties in my base object? This is not working...

```
DanubeDataSet.ProductsDataTable productTable = new DanubeDataSetTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter().GetProductByID(itemId);
    CartItem newItem = (CartItem)productTable[0];
    items.Add(newItem);
```

It can't cast from type DanubeDataSet.ProductsRow to CartItem. I understand why that is, but there has got to be a way to move the data of a ProductsRow to a CartItem since it contain all the properties of the ProductsRow. Am I wrong?

If you have a solution, keep in mind that I do not want to change the code in DanubeDataSet.ProductsRow since it is auto-generated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do with inheritance. However, there is a convenient way to do this using partial classes. Here's what you do: Open your data set, right click the design surface and select View Code from the context menu. This create a code-behind file for the data set. Then add your property as follows:

```
public partial class DanubeDataSet 
{
    partial class ProductsRow
    {
        public decimal TotalCost
        {
            get
            {
                return Quantity * Price;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I like your idea, but I am unable to follow your instructions. When I double click the DanubeDataSet.xsd to open the data set, View Code is not an option when I right click to show the context menu. There is only "Add" which expands to let me add a table adapter, datatable, query, etc. And "Preview Data", Properties. Suggestions?

Comment: I manually added the code behind file and it worked out. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why the View Code option wasn't available, it may be that your version of Visual Studio doesn't support this, even in the C# language does support it. I'm glad this worked out with a little manual effort.